# Return data in faster way from MySql

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I'm learning php and mysql. When I read `MySql` from `PHP-manual` I realized that,
to return data from `MySql` in faster ways is in ordered.

```
mysql_fetch_array() > mysql_fetch_row() > mysql_fetch_assoc()
```

mysql_fetch_array() is faster than mysql_fetch_row() and mysql_fetch_assoc().
Can I missing something?
**THANKS.......**

Comment: Congratulations! Are you asking why one is faster, how to use them, or what ?

Comment: Each one return different format.

Comment: I only idinitify these.

Comment: mysql_fetch_array is probably the fastest but by using it to large degree you are sacrificing code readability and maintainability for almost a negligible performance increase. if you are hitting a performance bottleneck then the problem is probably not what fetching mechanism you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're missing the big red warning that says these functions are all deprecated and should not be used. Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead.

In terms of performance, the real answer is: don't worry about it. The performance implications of accessing your MySQL data through objects or associative arrays is negligible. There are going to be much bigger performance issues in the way you write your queries and the rest of your software, and many of those aren't worth worrying about either.

See the classic [PrematureOptimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) article on c2.com.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of performance, you shouldn't use these [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) functions for a new project, look for the [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extensions.